# Python os.chdir error with extra backslashes

Tags: python

I am trying to change the cwd but using `os.path.join` however when i send the string to `os.chdir` it throws an error because the string has extract backslashes added. See code below:

```
      cwd = os.getcwd()
       if cwd != os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop"):
     try:
        path = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop") 

    print(path) #Added for debugging
    os.chdir(path)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The output is:

- Print statement -> `\Users\xxxx\Desktop`
- Error -> [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: `'\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop'`

What i have tried:
 - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239915/python-os-chdir-doesnt-seem-to-work)
 - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory/1810760)
 - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-change-directory-cd-in-python)

using .replace and trying to convert to a raw string. At first I just passed the entire `os.path.join` into `os.chdir`.

Comment: What does `dir \Users\xxxx\Desktop` from `cmd` show?

Comment: On Windows, with what is supposed to be an absolute path (leading backslash) you need to specify the drive letter as well: `os.path.join(os.environ['HOMEDRIVE'], os.environ['HOMEPATH'], "Desktop")`